# MacBook Pro Mid 2012 startup chime from right speaker only

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, efi, nvram

After installing a ssd into my Macbook pro mid 2012 (not retina), i noticed that the startup chime is coming only from the right speaker. (I am not sure if it was always like that or if its because of the installation). However when I am in the OS, both speakers work perfectly fine. I reseted the NVRAM a couple of times already. Is the chime supposed to come out of the right speaker only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure your MBP always did that. It is something annoying I never really liked about the MBP: They have a "subwoofer" which is situated on the right-hand side of the MacBook. So sounds with a lot of bass always appear to come from the right speaker. [Here](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203371) is what Apple says.

Comment: However if I find a sound of the chime online and play within the operating system, there is still a significant sound that comes out of the left speaker.

Comment: That's a good thing then, right? ;-)

Comment: Well its good to know that the speaker works, but why the chime at boot doesnt play on both speakers is kinda bothersome

Comment: OK, you seriously just made me reboot my MBP mid2012 (non-retina). Same thing: Sound comes only from right speaker. I could imagine that the boot OS does not have all the fancy sound drivers loaded yet and addresses only one speaker.

Comment: OH, you have the same laptop, well then i gues that is good enough confirmation lol, thanks